# On Productory Notation

Tags: notation, infinite-product

As the title says, it just a doubt about notation. Being more specific it's about the limit of the productory. For example, if we have

$\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^n (2i+1), \,\, n \in \mathbb{N}$

When $n=0$, do we have $i=0$? Or we just start computing the products when $n>i$?

Comment: If $n=0$ you just get the single term $(2\times 0+1)=1$.

Comment: So we do count. Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation 
$$
\prod_{i=j}^n f(i)
$$
denotes a product "*starting at $j$, and stopping at $n$*". So your product, for which $j=n=0$, gives
$$
\prod_{i=0}^0 (2i+1) = 2\times0+1=1.
$$

Comment: Including $n$, right?

Comment: @Mr.N Yes that is correct